# Reading data received from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase data in a variable i want to make that into an array.

```
 -L4DcN3qCO2_E4_oyDc2:{key: "Newyork", value: "Newyork"}
 -L4DcOOY1O0dZrqEDIx3:{key: "Chicago", value: "Chicago"}
 -L4DcQkNnMyFf8x3H-3i:{key: "Raleigh", value: "Raleigh"}
```

I want this data into a array like this.

```
      [{key: "Newyork", value: "Newyork"},
      {key: "Chicago", value: "Chicago"},
      {key: "Raleigh", value: "Raleigh"}]
```

What is the process to convert it into an array.

Please find the approaches i have tried below.

1st Approach:

```
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];
 elementData.options.forEach(ss => {
  this.options.push(ss.child('key'),ss.child('value'))
  });
```

2nd Approach

```
elementData.on('value', snap =>  {
   var data = [];
   snap.forEach(ss => {
   this.options.push(ss.child('key'),ss.child('value'))
     data.push(ss.child('key').val());
   });
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I am not able to loop through it as it is [Object] of [Object]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single line helped me.
Object.keys(elementData.options).map(e=>elementData.options[e])